# Is it redundant to encrypt files that are meant to be saved in the app-specific storage in the files directory?

Tags: android, encryption, android-storage

I am working on an android app where I am importing files to the app-specific storage inside the files directory.

As per the information in the documentation ([here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific))

> Internal storage directories: These directories include both a dedicated location for storing persistent files, and another location for storing cache data. The system prevents other apps from accessing these locations, and on Android 10 (API level 29) and higher, these locations are encrypted. These characteristics make these locations a good place to store sensitive data that only your app itself can access.

I have a minSDK requirement of 29, so not planning to make this app available for android versions below 10 and app will not work on rooted devices.

So, is it worth it to encrypt everything and then store the files or just import them in plaintext and store them as it is?

Comment: `importing files to the app-specific storage inside the files directory.` There are two of such storage locations. Which do you have in mind?

Comment: @blackapps The one under com.app.package_name

Comment: They are both under the package name.

Comment: @blackapps yes correct, my bad, I am talking about the one that is not on the shared storage, the one we get when we use the filesDir() method in activity